# How to work around spring support when installing a garage door opener?

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

I'm trying to help my brother with a garage door opener installation.  Normally this would be pretty straightforward, but his garage has a feature/obstacle I've never seen before.  The door installer used a piece of angle iron as a support for the door spring.  Unfortunately, it's in the same place where the opener's track is supposed to attach to the door header.

Why would the spring need a support like this?  And how should we work around it when installing the opener?

[image]

Comment: You know that spring has a murderous amount of torque on it. *Like, can literally kill you*.   Did you think it was just setting there?  I would think more that the angle iron is not enough.... and attached to a cripple wall to boot!

Comment: I don’t have much expert knowledge here, but I’ve seen door operators not on center before.  Can you relocate the opener?

Comment: @Harper Other garage door springs I've seen are attached directly to the door header with lag screws.  I've never seen the angle iron used this way before.  That being said, I have no plans to mess with the spring.  I just need a way to work around it.

Comment: @Tyson Good question.  If it can be installed off-center, I suspect we'd need to reinforce the door somehow at the place where the opener connects to it.  I'll look into that.

Comment: The spring doesn't need to be on center, but it does need to be attached to really beefy structure.  Sounds like in this case the available joist was on/near center, so the spring had to be.